# Convert Oracle Decode to Postgres Case expression

Tags: oracle, postgresql, case, decode, where-clause

We have an existing Oracle SQL query that needs to be converted to Postgres. The decode is complex for me and would love to get some help in converting to Postgres CASE please.

**Existing SQL:**

```
SELECT  P.t_id   p_t_id,
            Q.t_id   q_t_id
    FROM    pts Q,
            pts P
    WHERE   P.t_id <> Q.t_id
    AND   ((decode(substr(P.c_num,2,1),
                     '0',  1,
                     '1',  1,
                     '2',  1,
                     '3',  1,
                     '4',  1,
                     '5',  1,
                     '6',  1,
                     '7',  1,
                     '8',  1,
                     '9',  1,
                      0) != 0 
AND     P.c_num IS NOT NULL
...rest of query...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, I would phrase the query as:

```
select p.t_id p_t_id, q.t_id q_t_id
from pts q
inner join pts p on p.t_id <> q.t_id
where p.c_num ~ '^.\d'
```

Rationale:

- basically the `decode()` statement checks if the second character of string `p.c_num` is a digit. This looks more complicated that it needs to be (in Oracle as in Postgres). I find that is is simpler to use a regex for this - `'^.\d'` means: the beginning of the string (`^`), then any character (`.`), then a digit (`\d`). You could also use `in`:

```
substr(p.c_num, 1, 2) in ('0', '1', '2', ..., '9')
```

- the `not null` condition on `p.c_num` is unnecessary - `null` values do not match any regex (in Oracle, they would pass the `decode()` test either)
- use standard joins (with the `on` keyword), rather than old-school implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause)

Comment: Awesome and thank you so much @GMB for an immediate and precise answer. Will check and mark the answer as correct soon. Thanks